# How can I solve bound issue from nested loop?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String CAMBRIDGE = "CAMBRIDGE";

        System.out.println("Enter word.");
        String word = sc.nextLine();

        StringBuilder wordSB = new StringBuilder(word);
        StringBuilder camSB = new StringBuilder(CAMBRIDGE);

        System.out.println(wordSB.length());
        System.out.println(camSB.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < wordSB.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < camSB.length(); j++) {
                if (wordSB.charAt(i) == camSB.charAt(j)) {
                    System.out.println(wordSB.charAt(i));
                    System.out.println(camSB.charAt(j));
                    wordSB.deleteCharAt(i);
                } // end if
            } // end second for
        } // end for

        System.out.println(wordSB.toString());
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

I was trying to compare duplicated element, but I got "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 3, length 3" error message from this line when I enter LOVA as an input for checking duplicated letter A.

```
if (wordSB.charAt(i) == camSB.charAt(j))
```

I assume the issue is from the nested for loop, but I couldn't figure out how to solve that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting characters from a string while using its length to iterate over it. Removing/Deleting a char will shorten the string -> the character at index i w won't be the one you expected, resulting in a out of bounds exception at the end, because you keep skipping characters.

Try it out with a simple println of the string while removing the chars with the same for-loop and you will understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The line `wordSB.deleteCharAt(i);` removes a character from `wordSB`, which means that the index `i` may point to something that is no longer there. This can be problematic once your inner for-loop iterates to the next value of `j`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you may want to break from your inner-loop after you've deleted the character by adding a `break;` after the `wordSB.deleteCharAt(i);` line.